# Angular: updating view with value passed from directive to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller, highmaps

Budding web developer here struggling with updating the view from my controller. 

I'm using highmaps and angular to build a neat selection tool for my web app. I've got a directive nested inside the scope of a controller. I would like this directive to update a value (`selectedCountry`) stored in the controller. Then, I'd like the controller to display the up to date `selectedCountry` value on the view.

I've checked that the directive is passing the correct `selectedCountry` value to the parent controller. However, the controller is not updating the view to match the updated value. I would greatly appreciate if someone could take a look at this.

Demo Here: http://jsfiddle.net/frauLLmr/5/

`index.html`

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="GraphController as graphCtrl">
    <div> {{graphCtrl.showSelectedCountry()}} </div>
    <div> {{graphCtrl.selectedCountry}} </div>
    <high-chart-directive update-selected-country='graphCtrl.updateSelectedCountry(newCountry)'></high-chart-directive>
  </div>
</div>
```

`app.js`

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('GraphController', function() {
  var self = this;
  self.selectedCountry = 'unselected';
  var outsideScopeTest = function() {
    alert('selectedCountry (from controller scope): ' 
        + self.selectedCountry);
  };
  self.updateSelectedCountry = function(newCountry) {
    self.selectedCountry = newCountry;
    outsideScopeTest();
  };
  self.showSelectedCountry = function() {
    return self.selectedCountry;
  };
});

myApp.directive('highChartDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      updateSelectedCountry: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      Highcharts.mapChart(element[0], getMapOptions(mapClick));

      function mapClick(event) {
        scope.updateSelectedCountry({newCountry: event.point.name});
        alert('selectedCountry (from directive scope): ' 
        + event.point.name);
      }
    }
  };

  function getMapOptions(callback) {
    return {
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
      mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
          verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
      },
      series: [{
        data: getTestCountries(),
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world-highres'],
        // TODO-chantelle: figure out how geoJSON joinBy works
        joinBy: 'hc-key',
        name: 'Emission per capita',
        states: {
          hover: {
            color: '#9370DB'
          }
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false,
          format: '{point.name}'
        }
      }],
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          events: {
            click: function(event) {
              callback(event);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };
  }

  function getTestCountries() {
    return [{
      "hc-key": "ca",
      "value": 0
    }, {
      "hc-key": "br",
      "value": 1
    }, {
      "hc-key": "ru",
      "value": 2
    }];
  }
});
```

Comment: have you tried it already with google maps?, show all your code please, I mean the css and all the things, Let me see, if I got it right. you want the selected country change the color when selected?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @OtávioBarreto! I don't have any css yet. I actually want the word 'unselected' to change to the name of the selected country when a user clicks on the map.

Comment: see my answer don't sure if it's Exactly what you want, Weijian also gave a example below you needed to `// force angular update
    $scope.$apply();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is that  Highcharts.mapChart(element[0], getMapOptions(mapClick)); is not part of the angular scope. So any calls here will not trigger the angular app to refresh. You need to force angular to update using $scope.apply();

```
var outsideScopeTest = function() {
    alert('selectedCountry (from controller scope): ' 
    + selfc.selectedCountry);

    // force angular update
    $scope.$apply();

};
```

Comment: I see! Thank you @Weijian!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="GraphController as graphCtrl">
    <div> {{graphCtrl.showSelectedCountry()}} </div>
    <div> {{graphCtrl.selectedCountry}} </div>
    <high-chart-directive update-selected-country='graphCtrl.updateSelectedCountry(newCountry)'></high-chart-directive>
  </div>
</div>
```

the js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('GraphController', function($scope) {
  var self = this;
  self.selectedCountry = 'unselected';
  var outsideScopeTest = function() {
    alert('selectedCountry (from controller scope): ' 
        + self.selectedCountry);
      $scope.$apply();
  };
  self.updateSelectedCountry = function(newCountry) {
    self.selectedCountry = newCountry;
    outsideScopeTest();
  };
  self.showSelectedCountry = function() {
    return self.selectedCountry;
  };
});

myApp.directive('highChartDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      updateSelectedCountry: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      Highcharts.mapChart(element[0], getMapOptions(mapClick));

      function mapClick(event) {
        scope.updateSelectedCountry({newCountry: event.point.name});
        alert('selectedCountry (from directive scope): ' 
        + event.point.name);
      }
    }
  };

  function getMapOptions(callback) {
    return {
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
      mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
          verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
      },
      series: [{
        data: getTestCountries(),
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world-highres'],
        // TODO-chantelle: figure out how geoJSON joinBy works
        joinBy: 'hc-key',
        name: 'Emission per capita',
        states: {
          hover: {
            color: '#9370DB'
          }
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false,
          format: '{point.name}'
        }
      }],
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          events: {
            click: function(event) {
              callback(event);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };
  }

  function getTestCountries() {
    return [{
      "hc-key": "ca",
      "value": 0
    }, {
      "hc-key": "br",
      "value": 1
    }, {
      "hc-key": "ru",
      "value": 2
    }];
  }
});
```